# C# Call custom COM+ error: 80070005 Access is denied

Tags: c#, com+, dcom

System.UnauthorizedAccessException: 'Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID  failed due to the following error: 80070005 Access is denied. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070005 (E_ACCESSDENIED)).'

The code is calling a web method that that calls a custom dcom application.
The web service has been set to run on 32 bit on IIS.

DCom CLSID does exist and I have checked permission.

Comment: You can try out `dcomcnfg.msc` and see if that really is just a problem with access permission to given component. However, most probably, that component needs 'administrator' rights, you may try out that first. Other than that, millions of things could have happened.

Comment: In terms of COM components, they like to be different. If they were not, you'd find your answer just by pasting error code to google. It failed right? you've probably got tons of hits, but neither really helpful. That's because 8007005 is VERY generic error. Without details like what component was that, how you tried to accessing it, what win-OS and COM version you have, what account and access rights are set in dcomcnfg, etc, it's hard to guess. In general, when you ask about 'why my code throws/crashes/etc'' it's good to show the piece of code, or at least provide as much detail as possible!

Comment: I get a lot of results nothing helps. The error is all that I get. The code is calling a web method that that calls a custom dcom application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Uninstalled and re-installing the custom Dcom application resolved my issue.

Comment: Thanks for leaving a follow-up after resolving your issue. If reinstall helped, then most probably it really was all about broken permissions on the component - i.e. it was installed by userA for himself, and you tried to use it from account of userB. `dcomcnfg.msc` could help you fix that without reinstalling, but probably reinstalling was faster/easier.